# Prevent Excel Conditional Formatting from fragmenting when deleting row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Using Excel 2016.

In the "Applies To" Section, I have `=$F:$F` because I want it to apply to column F

In the 'rule' the formula is `=AND($F1=$F2,NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))`

Intent: Highlight cells, in Column F, that have a value equal to the cell below it. This is intended to call out that it's okay to delete this row if you want to, because the next row has the same value in column F. (And also doesn't highlight blank cells.) (The selection of which rows to delete or not is manual and based on other criteria not relevant here.)

So after putting in the formula and the 'applies to' section it works exactly as intended.

But when I delete any row, the 'applies to' section fragments and everything breaks.

As an example, cells F187, F188, and F189 all have the same data. Cells F187 and F188 are highlighted correctly. I right click row 188 and delete it. Cell F187 loses its highlight even though the 'new' value in Cell F188 is the same. The entire point of the highlighting is now broken because it's not correctly calling out that F187 is still a row that's safe to delete. I go to check the conditional formatting rule and see the "applies to" is now `=$F$1:$F$186,$F$188:$F$1048574`

How do I prevent this from happening every time I delete a row? I want the "applies to" to be permanent and never change any time I perform an operation like deleting a row. I wish there was some kind of 'lock' function that I could 'lock' the 'applies to' and make it stop fragmenting.

Not sure if it's relevant but some rows are merged across columns. For instance on row 179 the cells from columns A to H are merged.

I searched around and found something that said to try named ranges or using the indirect function, but that may work elsewhere, but it does NOT work in the 'applies to' in the conditional formatting rules manager, unfortunately.

Would prefer to avoid VBA script solution, but will consider one if it's one that occurs automatically in the background and the sheet could otherwise be used as normal.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You could try using `=AND(COUNTIF(F:F,F1)>1,NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))` for your condition -- note this will highlight cells with duplicate values anywhere in column `F`, not just duplicate values immediately above, but by  avoiding the reference to specific rows, you circumvent the problem with the condition

Comment: The best practice is not to delete rows. Instead clear the contents and re-sort the values.  Then it will not happen.  Same with insert, add to the bottom then sort.

Comment: It's really bad practice to apply CF to whole columns. Excel will have to evaluate over a million cells for each CF column EVERY time ANY value in the workbook is changed. Notice that the workbook is performing slower? That's why. Use Excel Tables and apply the CF to the table column. The format will be applied to new rows automatically.  -- The fragmentation of CF is a known issue in Excel.

Comment: Refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565724/conditional-formatting-doesnt-update-when-i-delete-a-row

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - It's intended for there to be duplicate values elsewhere in column F, but the highlight should only apply if it's immediately above or below. This solution would work for some but not for what I need.

Comment: @Scott Craner - This table is not sorted. Performing any kind of sort operation on this data would be catastrophic to its integrity. I considered making an index value and sorting on that but rows are inserted or deleted all the time which would make keeping the index values accurate a pain.

Comment: @tylyn - Turning this field into an actual 'table' in excel destroys the rows (I call them 'section headers') that are merged & centered and seems to block them from being recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "Applies to" range is breaking when you delete row 188 because your conditional itself is also breaking. After the deletion, do you see that in addition to the "Applies to" range of the main conditional being split, a new conditional applying only to cell F187 has been created. So instead of cell F187 being covered by the original:

`=AND($F1=$F2,NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))`

it now has its own line of the form,

`=AND($F187=#REF!,NOT(ISBLANK($F187)))`

One way to handle that is to make the conditional itself immune to the deletion. For example, this seems to do what you are after (I've removed the blank cell check for clarity):

`=$F1=OFFSET($F$1,ROW($F1),0))`

The fact that the position of the next cell down is being calculated rather than stated explicitly is what makes it less fragile under the deletion. That's almost certainly why one of the recommendations you saw was to use INDIRECT(). It, too, defers calculation of the cell reference (until "runtime" as it were), which renders it more robust in the face of structural changes like row deletion.

---

OK, now I said I omitted the blank cell check for clarity but that was only half true. The other reason is that I simply cannot get a blank cell check to work! I've tried:

`=AND($F1=OFFSET($F$1,ROW($F1),0)),NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))`

and

`=IF(LEN($F1)=0,FALSE,$F1=OFFSET($F$1,ROW($F1),0))`

and even, just as a test, replacing the blank check with a hard TRUE:

`=AND($F1=OFFSET($F$1,ROW($F1),0)),TRUE)`

but none of them work. They all return FALSE, regardless of the data in the cells. And I don't know why.

Anyway: the first part of my answer does give you one option for your core problem. Figuring out why adding the blank cell check breaks it is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

P.S. A hackish workaround for that blank cell check problem is to move the conditional into a helper column (i.e. one containing the conditional as an actual formula). Then your format conditional itself would simply be a reference to that helper column. Why it doesn't work when inserted as the format conditional itself, I don't know. I say this is hackish because it doesn't handle the fact that you're trying to apply this formatting to all of column F. Shrug.

Comment: The offset formula seems to work great, but has the lack of blank check like you called out. My current workaround idea is to have a conditional formatting for the blank check that's "stop if true" and have this after, but, leaving this question open in case anyone can figure out why adding the blank check breaks this. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me, if you can figure out why and edit your answer I'll mark it as solution. I also tweaked it for 'above or below' check instead of just below.

`AND(OR($F1=OFFSET($F1,-1,0),$F1=OFFSET($F1,1,0)),NOT(ISBLANK($F1)))`